# performance and limitation in join - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

my query is :

```
  $this->db->select('users.id as user_id');
    $this->db->select('users.username');
    $this->db->select('users.family');
    $this->db->select('users.name');
    $this->db->select('users.phone');
    $this->db->select('traction_details.title');
    $this->db->select('traction_details.tr_id');
    $this->db->select('tractions.buy_id');
    $this->db->select('tractions.coupon_code');
    $this->db->select('tractions.coupon_property_id');
    $this->db->select('tractions.expired');
    $this->db->select('tractions.date');

    $this->db->from('tractions');


    $this->db->join('traction_details' , 'traction_details.tr_id = tractions.id');
    $this->db->join('users' , 'tractions.user_id = users.id');
    $this->db->join('coupon_cats' , 'tractions.coupon_parent = coupon_cats.coupon_id');
    $this->db->join('coupons' , 'coupons.id = tractions.coupon_parent');
    $this->db->join('tractions_delivery' , 'tractions_delivery.tr_id = tractions.id');
    $this->db->where('coupon_cats.cat_id =' , '13');
    $this->db->where('tractions.succ =' , '1');

    $this->db->group_by('tractions.buy_id');
    $this->db->order_by('traction_details.tr_id', 'desc');
    $this->db->limit( $limit , $offset );
```

my query is very slow and it takes over 15-20 seconds .

my `traction` table has 188460 records. is it possible to to join this table where `id` is more than 170000 ? because less that it I don't want to join.
I think this limitation increase the speed of it. yeah ?

Comment: Just add to the where > where tractions.id > 170000

Comment: ok, but it doesn't speed of my query .

Comment: You should execute your query with the keyword `EXPLAIN` in front of it. This will give you a - more or less - detailed explanation of all the tables included in your Query and which types of indexes the Query has used. Please add the output of this EXPLAIN here, otherwise we can only guess whats slowing down.

Comment: I would also to Martin's note that you should also post the create table statements for all affected tables, so we can see the existing fields and the indexes.

Comment: Please post the actual query instead of whatever unreadable $ based nonsense this is